# Specify order for {select_member_groups} output

Tags: ee2, solspace-user

So as the title states, I want to specify an order for the output of the `{select_member_groups}` tag pair within `{exp:user:register}`.

I am allowing users to register in one of three member groups with ids 5, 8 and 9. This displays in ID order, however I want to be able to have them output in the order 8, 9, 5.

So I tried to do:

```
{exp:user:register allowed_groups="8|9|5"}
```

but it still outputs in the order 5, 8, 9 on the front end. I've tried various parameters on the `{select_member_groups}` tag and none seem to work. Can't see anything about ordering it on the docs either.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

If it helps the EE version is 2.9.2 and User version is 3.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of this writing the ordering of the `{select_member_groups}` is based on default database order (i.e. increasing group_id), and not the order set in the `allowed_groups=""` parameter. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

In the meantime, using EE's `{exp:query}` module could get you similar data. For example:

```
<select name="group_id">
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT group_id, group_title
                FROM    exp_member_groups
                WHERE   group_id IN (8,9,5)
                ORDER BY FIELD(group_id, 8,9,5)"}
   <option value="{group_id}"}>{group_title}</option>
{/exp:query}
</select>
```